# Is there a way to combine four numbers into one and still be able do check the individual values?

Tags: coding-theory

I do have four separate values in my script and in order for them to be processed further they need to be somehow combined into one and I have to be able to read the one  combined number without alteration and know the values of the four.
The first is either 1/0 and the three are numbers 0-99 with one decimal place.
I am sorry if it is a dumb question, but I can't think of anything clever right now.
Thank you very much

Comment: Can't you just write down a number where the digits are made up of your four numbers? E.g. if there are just two numbers $98.2$ and $31.9$, you could just write $982319$.

Comment: Simpler if you declare that the back three have to be written with two digits each.  Thus, if your second number is $0$, write it as $00$, and so on.  Then you can just string them together.  If, say, your numbers were $\{1,0,1,37\}$ then you would write $1000137$.

Comment: Yes, but I need to be able to say - second value is bigger then X just by looking at the one number. The number is an input for another script, so a computer must be able to decide.

Comment: Why didn't you describe all the requirements in the question body? Anyway, there are two possible values for first number (=1 bit), and 1000 possible values for the remaining three. As $1000<2^{10}$ you need ten bits for each of the others. A total of 31 bits, which will fit comfortably into a 32-bit integer. To take a look at the second number you mask out the other 21 bits. Piece of cake. By the way, this has nothing to do with coding theory. I'm not sure about the best tag, but it ain't coding theory :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following lulu's suggestion, if your numbers are $a,b,c,d$ you could make your combined number $n=a10^6+b10^4+c10^2+d$.  To extract $b$ you can take $(n \bmod 10^6) \operatorname { div } 10^4$ where the div is integer divide.

Comment: Sounds really good, will try - thank you!