# Combining numbers reversibly and be able to iterate one of them sequentially?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinations

Taking a hint from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1867569/is-there-a-way-to-combine-four-numbers-into-one-and-still-be-able-do-check-the-i), a friend had created a similar formula where he had to combine 4 numbers `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`.

Here, `a` is let's say the 3rd element from a set of A number of elements.
`b` is let's say the 5th element from a set of B number of elements.
`c` is the 4th element from a set of C number of elements.
`d` is the 2nd element from a set of D number of elements.

To combine it, he used:
`combinedNum = a*A + b*B + c*C + d*D + 1`

The problem here is that if I want to iterate `combinedNum` for the 15th to the 35th elements of `C`, then `combinedNum15`, `combinedNum16`, `combinedNum17`... `combinedNum35` won't be consecutive numbers.

Same if I want to iterate the elements of `A`, `B` or `D`. Is there a way to get combinedNum's for each of them in such a way that I'd be able to get combinedNum for the 14th element of `B` and just add 1 to get the combinedNum for the 15th element of `B`?

ps: The necessity of being able to "add 1" to get the next value is because `combinedNum`'s will be stored in a database and I need to find the `combinedNum`'s of a sequence of either `A`, `B`, `C` or `D` that lie within a certain range. I can't do that if they aren't consecutive. Also, `combinedNum` can't go beyond the value `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`.

**UPDATE:** An example would be if a=12, b=2, c=5, d=6 and using some formula, `combinedNum` = 3255. Keeping b=2, c=5, d=6 constant, if I increment a to 13, 14, 15...., then I'd want combinedNum also to increase as `3256, 3257, 3258...`. OR, if I keep a=12, c=5, d=6 constant, then b=1 to b=B should yield consecutive combinedNum's x, x+1, x+2, x+3... (x+B-1). I know this isn't possible to do with the existing formula shown above, but is there any possible way?

Comment: So, suppose you start with the combinedNum value for (a,b,c,d), where say b=14 and c=7. You want to be able to add 1 to this combinedNum value to get the combinedNum value when b is changed from 14 to 15 ... but you also want to be able to add 1 to the original combinedNum value to get the combinedNum value when c is changed from 7 to 8?

Comment: Kind of. I've updated the question with an example. I know it isn't possible using the existing formula, but was hoping there would be a way.

Comment: First of all, the formula $a+b+c+d$ does the job, and is essentially the only function that does. But I'm inferring that you want combinedNum to uniquely determine the original quadruple; and that's impossible given this property you want. For example, using your example of $a=12,b=2,c=5,d=6$, where combinedNum is 3255: all the quadruples $a=13,b=2,c=5,d=6$ and $a=12,b=3,c=5,d=6$ and $a=12,b=2,c=6,d=6$ and $a=12,b=2,c=5,d=7$ would make combinedNum equal to 3256.